# What does this code do in Perl: keys(%$hash) ...?

Tags: perl

```
print "Enter the hash \n";
$hash=<STDIN>;chop($hash);
@keys = keys (%$hash);
@values = values (%$hash);
```

Since Google ignores special characters there was no way I could find what the "%$hash" thing does and how this is suppossed to work

Comment: Do you have a good Perl primer?

Comment: It probably fails miserably, since there's no conversion of `$hash` from a string to a hash reference.

Comment: Fine, it's probably just wrong then

Comment: Yes, pretty much; https://eval.in/457326

Comment: Disregarding your actual code and focusing on the title, first, `%$hash` dereferences a hash reference (`$hash`). `keys()` then iterates over the hash and returns a list of all of its keys. See http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/perldoc-html/functions/keys.html

Comment: @stevieb: `keys` does no iteration. It simply returns a list of the hash's keys

Answer (score 3):

`keys(%$hash)` returns the keys of the hash referenced by the value in `$hash`. A hash is a type of associative array, which (more or less) means an array that's indexed by strings (called "keys") instead of by numbers.

In this particular case, `$hash` contains a string. When one uses a string as a reference, dereferencing it access the package variable whose name matches the string.

If the full program is

```
%FOO = ( a=>1, b=>2 );
%BAR = ( c=>3, d=>4 );
print "Enter the hash \n";
$hash=<STDIN>;chop($hash);
@keys = keys(%$hash);
```

Then,

- `@keys` will contains `a` and `b` if the user enters `FOO`.
- `@keys` will contains `c` and `d` if the user enters `BAR`.
- `@keys` will contains `E2BIG`, `EACCES`, `EADDRINUSE` and many more if the user enters `!`.
- `@keys` can contains paths if the user enters `INC`.
- `@keys` will be empty for most other values.

(The keys are returned in an arbitrary order.)

The last three cases are surely unintentional. This is why the posted code is awful code. This is what the code should have been:

```
use strict;             # Always use these as they
use warnings 'all';     #   find/prevent numerous errors.

my %FOO = ( a=>1, b=>2 );
my %BAR = ( c=>3, d=>4 );

my %inputs = ( FOO => \%FOO, BAR => \%BAR );

print "Enter the name of a hash: ";
my $hash_name = <STDIN>;
chomp($hash_name);
my $hash = $inputs{$hash_name}
   or die("No such hash\n");

my @keys = keys(%$hash);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is nonsensical, but what it *should* be doing is dereferencing a hash reference, provided that you have a valid hash reference stored in your scalar `$hash` (which you don't).

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

my $href = {
    foo => 'bar',
    bat => 'baz',
};

dd(keys(%$href));    # ("bat", "foo")
dd(values(%$href));  # ("baz", "bar")
```

---

The [`keys()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) function will return a list consisting of all the keys of the hash.

> The returned values are copies of the original keys in the hash, so
>   modifying them will not affect the original hash.

The [`values()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) function does the exact same thing, except with the values of the hash (obviously).

> So long as a given hash is unmodified you may rely on `keys`, `values` and
>   `each` to repeatedly return the same order as each other.

---

For more help with references, see [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), and maybe [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) if you're feeling adventurous.

Comment: You should add a note about `keys()`

Comment: @stevieb Could you be more specific? There are lots of notes I could add about `keys()`... ;-)

Comment: OP asked specifically what `keys %$hash` does. You got the deref part, but didn't include an explanation for the `keys()` function in your answer

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. When I saw `keys()` and `values()` both trying to dereference something that wasn't a reference, I assumed the stumbling block was with references, not with `keys()`.

Answer (score 1):

`keys()` returns the keys of the specified hash.  In the code you wrote, the name of the hash to look at (and extract the keys and values of) is being specified via `STDIN`, which is really bizarre behavior.